# Error while generating spree site

Tags: spree

I am trying to generate a spree site, I have created the rails app, and within its gem file added the following line :
 **gem "spree","~> 1.0.3"**

now whenever I try to bundle install m getting the following error:
**Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    spree (~> 1.0.3) ruby depends on
      jquery-rails (<= 1.0.19, >= 1.0.18) ruby
    jquery-rails (2.0.2)**

please sugggest appropriate solution

Comment: Which version of rails are you using? Please make sure your bundle install works without spree and that your rails version is supported by the spree version you are trying to install

Comment: Please show the Gemfile.

Comment: @ ashga: How can I know that which spree version supports which rails version.

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you get an error that Bundler could not find compatible versions for "gem-name", always first try a simple `gem install gem-name`. If that works, try `bundle install` again. This seems to clear up far more bundler problems than it really should.

Failing that, are you using Ruby MRI, or something more exotic, like JRuby?